# Requesting Definitions Using the Wordnik API

Tags: c#, .net, api

I've only worked with APIs in a very minimal sense so I've been wanting to try out how to do this for some time.  Ok so this is what I have so far and it works but it returns everything of the definition.  So I have a few questions:

1. Is there a way to request just the definitions without anything else?
2. Do I just parse the data? I saw in the Wordnik API and I can include XML tags...so can I use an XMLReader to grab the definitions?
3. Now how about requesting both the definitions and if it is noun/verb/etc at once?

The ultimate goal would be to create a list of definitions that I could do stuff with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's my code so far:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string apiKey = "***************";
        string wordToSearch = "";

        do
         {
            Console.Write("Please type a word to get the definition: ");
            wordToSearch = Console.ReadLine();

            if (!wordToSearch.Equals("q"))
            {
                string url = "http://api.wordnik.com/v4/word.json/" + wordToSearch + "/definitions?api_key=" + apiKey;
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        string responseFromWordnik = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(responseFromWordnik);
                    }
                }
            }

        } while (!wordToSearch.Equals("q"));
    }
}
```

thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to get definitions for a word. You need to replace the api key with your own api key.

```
public class Word
{
    public string word { get; set; }
    public string sourceDictionary { get; set; }
    public string partOfSpeech { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class WordList
{
    public List<Word> wordList { get; set; }
}


string url = "http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/" + word + "/definitions?limit=200&includeRelated=false&sourceDictionaries=all&useCanonical=false&includeTags=false&api_key=a2a73e7b926c924fad7001ca3111acd55af2ffabf50eb4ae5";

HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36";
webRequest.Referer = "http://developer.wordnik.com/docs.html";
webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
webRequest.Host = "api.wordnik.com";

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

string enc = webResponse.ContentEncoding;
using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    String responseString = "{\"wordList\":" + reader.ReadToEnd() + "}";

    if (responseString != null)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        WordList words = ser.Deserialize<WordList>(responseString);    

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The API documentation will probably tell you that.
2. Yes, parse the data. If the data is coming down as XML, then you can parse it with an XMLReader, or you can load it into an XMLDocument. It looks like you're asking for JSON, though. If so, you'll want a JSON parser. Check out [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/).
3. Again, check out the API documentation.

Their documentation page is suspiciously sparse. You'll probably get better response on their Google group or one of the other sources listed on their [support page](http://developer.wordnik.com/#!/support).